# Possible to lock the page when more than one admin editing the same content?

Tags: magento, concurrency, permissions, admin

My store have multiple admin users, sometimes more than one users are editing the same content/product.

Is it possible for magento to check it with "first come first serve", reserve the editing rights for the first comer, and the later one cannot edit the content? Or magento already has similar solution? (Concurrent editing)

Hope anyone could answer it , thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good start point is the [Cartware CmsLock](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/cartware-cmslock.html) module, which allows a page or static block to be locked. You can customise around it and lock and unlock when someone access the edit page.

Comment: @VikasKumar yes, you can apply the same concept to lock the product edit page, but catalog/product is editable through API, so you need to implement this on API access as well.